# How to control the language in which model validation errors are displayed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

In an ASP.NET MVC application, changing the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture[UI] can change the way MVC picks messages from resources. In the example application I've created to present the problem, there are two resource file - Res.resx for the English messages and Res.es.resx for the Spanish messages.

However, error messages resulting from the model validation always display in English.

My question is, **how can I control the language in which the model validation error messages are displayed?**

Below are parts of an example application I've wrote (based on the default ASP.NET MVC application) to demonstrate this problem.

Screenshots of how it looks in the browser:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4453002/SO_LanguageOfValidation.png

ViewModel and Controller - HomeController.cs :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SO_ValidationMessageInEnglish.Controllers {

  /// <summary>
  /// A very basic view model.
  /// </summary>
  public class ViewModel {

    [Display(Name = "Message", ResourceType = typeof(Res))]
    [DisplayName("Message")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MessageRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Res))]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
  }

  public class HomeController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index(string language = "en") {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult IndexPost(ViewModel foo) {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(foo.Language ?? "en");
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(foo.Language ?? "en");
      return View(foo);
    }

  }
}
```

View - Index.cshtml :

```
@model SO_ValidationMessageInEnglish.Controllers.ViewModel
@using SO_ValidationMessageInEnglish
@{ ViewBag.Title = Res.Title; }
@Res.CurrentMessage:<br />
<h2>@((Model != null) ? Model.Message : Res.Default)</h2>
<p />    
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null)) {        
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Language)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
    <input type="submit" value="@Res.Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also run into the same problem. When the model binder has invalid data it runs before the ActionFilter(s).

I didn't like the proposed solutions because messing with the routing was not my preferred solution. Listen for Application_AcquireRequestState is problematic because this event fire for each and every request, not just for requests that will be routed into MVC controllers.

I've end up writing a custom implementation of `IControllerFactory` that use `DefaultControllerFactory` internally and execute the localization code inside `CreateController` method.
This is not ideal either, hope it helps.

```
  public class PluggableControllerFactory : IControllerFactory {

    private readonly IControllerFactory innerControllerFactory;

    public PluggableControllerFactory() {
      innerControllerFactory = new DefaultControllerFactory();
    }

    public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) {
      // Run your culture localization here

      return innerControllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    }

    public System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) {
      return innerControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(requestContext, controllerName);
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller) {
      innerControllerFactory.ReleaseController(controller);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: In the Application_Start in Global.asax.cs, I've added the following line: `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new PluggableControllerFactory());` and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses full culture code to pick up the resource file as first choice. Rename `Res.es.resx` to `Res.es-ES.resx` and see if that works.

Comment: the issue here is the validation message, the rest of the texts are displayed well in Spanish. It seems that the validation messages are determined before the actions (and any action filters as well, from what we've seen), so the culture setting does not apply when they are picked from the resource file. I am looking for all the possible ways for determining the culture before the model validation happens, for each incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, one way to do that is to use your own model binder (although that might cause other problems in some situations). That will execute only when there is a model on the action, thus you might have to set the culture in two places (one for all actions and this for the model validation in particular):

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{

    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        var un = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(un))
        {
            var userLanguageCode = .......
            var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(userLanguageCode ?? "en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a different and in my opinion better solution that requires less work. In the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Run your culture localization here

}
```